# Creating two arrays with malloc on the same line

Tags: c++, c, arrays, memory, malloc

In C/C++ you can initialize a set of variables to the same value by this syntax: `a = b = c = 1;`

Would this work for `malloc`? I.E. something along the lines of:

```
char *a, *b;
a = b = malloc(SOME_SIZE * sizeof(char));
```

Would this create two arrays of the same size, but each has its own memory? Or would it assign both arrays to the same place in address space?

Comment: `a = malloc(asize), b = malloc(bsize)` or `a = (b = malloc(asize+bsize)) +  bsize`, but who in the world wants this complication instead of an extra line? Warning: In latter method you need to free only `b`.

Comment: In C++ you'd write `std::string a,b;` and be done with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you break down your multiple assign line to single assignment lines, the solution would become more clear to you.

```
a = b = malloc(SOME_SIZE * sizeof(char));
```

OR

```
b = malloc(SOME_SIZE * sizeof(char)); // b points to the alloced memory
a = b; // a got the value of b i.e., a points to where b is pointing.
```

Answer (score 3):

> Would this create two arrays of the same size, but each has its own memory?

No.

> Or would it assign both arrays to the same place in address space?

It would assign both pointers to the same address, i.e. Both pointer `a` and `b` will point to the same allocated memory location.

In case of

```
int a, b, c;
a = b = c = 1;
```

compiler allocates memory for all variables `a`, `b` and `c` to store an `int` data type and then assigns `1` to each memory location. All memory location has its own copy of that data.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
#define SOME_SIZE 20
int main()
{

      char *a, *b;
      a = b = (char *)malloc(SOME_SIZE * sizeof(char));
      strcpy(a,"You Are Right");

      cout << &(*a) << endl;
      cout << &(*b) << endl;
      return 0;
}
```

OutPut:

You Are Right

You Are Right

- from this its clear that Both Points to the Same Memory Area.

Comment: @haccks, Nishant :: My apologies. Now, I see, what you were talking about. The code Nishant has posted is C++. It took some time for me to switch the context from OP's code to his. My bad. I will delete my comment.